# Formatting API data for client side in a Google Script web app

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I am pulling data via a CRM API and successfully rendering that data in the front end of my Google Script web app.  But manipulating or formatting this data for the front end is a challenge for me.

In the code below, the `Potential Name` on the second line is rendering the correct data to the page.  But the first line called `Quote` is showing undefined.  This data is the data I am trying to format so that only the last six characters or the string are printed to the page.

Clearly, I must be trying to access the data from the API incorrectly.  Could someone please provide me with the correct way to manipulate this data in Google Scripts?

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
    var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Allied-po');
    templ.data = requestRecordFromCRM();
    return templ.evaluate()
        .setTitle('Purchase Order')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

/*Fetch record data from CRM*/
function requestRecordFromCRM() {
    requestedId = '1234';
    var authToken = 'XXXX';
    var zohoRequestUrl = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Potentials/getRecordById?&authtoken=' + authToken + '&scope=crmapi&id=' + requestedId;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(zohoRequestUrl);
    var sanitizedResponse = (response.getContentText());

    /*Sanitize json*/
    var output = JSON.parse(sanitizedResponse);
    Logger.log(output);

    /*Declare the variables you want to print*/
    var parsedOutput = output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL;
    var recordObj = {}

    Logger.log(typeof output)
    Logger.log(output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL.length)

    for (var i = 0; i < output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL.length; i++) {
      if (output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL[i].val == 'Potential Name') {
        recordObj.potentialName = output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL[i].content
      } 
    }

    return (recordObj);
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_blank">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Purchase Order</title>
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
         Quote: <span id="job-number"><?= data.potentialName ?></span>
      </div>
      <div>
         Potential Name: <?= data.potentialName ?>
      </div>
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Javascript').getContent(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript.html**

```
    <!-- Load jQuery, jQuery UI, and Bootstrap libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Format Job Numbers - return only last six characters in potentialName string
        (function() {

          var parts = document.getElementById('job-number');
          var selectedPart = parts.split(":");
          var thePart = selectedPart[0];

          return (thePart);
        }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular code retrieves the HTML element but not the innerHTML text

```
 var parts = document.getElementById('job-number');
```

Instead do this to get the embedded HTML which can used to split the string like so:

```
var parts = document.getElementById('job-number').innerHTML;
```

The final code will look like this:

```
<script>
        //Format Job Numbers - return only last six characters in potentialName string
   (function() {
      var parts = document.getElementById('job-number');
      var selectedPart = parts.innerHTML.split(":");
      console.log(parts)
      console.log(selectedPart)
      var thePart = selectedPart[1];
      parts.innerHTML = thePart
      return (thePart);
    }());

</script>
```

There is limited information on how the object structure looks like? The assumption here is there is six character before ":" in the data.potentialName value. if you rather want exactly six characters you can do this:

```
var selectedPart = parts.subString(0,6)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but it's still not printing an edited version of the string to the page.  The object normally looks something this:  *Company ABC: 123456*.  We're trying to get the last six numbers.  But even with these changes it's still printing the full string, *Company ABC: 123456*.

Comment: Yup, that was it!  Thank you!!